# Java: What does the following method do?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 String[] months = ("jan","Feb", "March", "April", .... , "Dec");
 System.out.println(months[Integer.parseInt(args[0]-1)]);
}
```

Why args[0]-1 ?

Comment: this is an outright off-topic, totally ignoring what Programmers is **[about]**. Why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: Thank u I did. But even Java tags don't exist there. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Have you run the code?  Looked at the `months[]` array in a debugger?

Comment: What is that language? It looks similar to, but not quite, Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking input for the month, 1-12 . But since arrays start at 0 so we have to minus 1 from the input otherwise if we enter 1 for Jan it will show Feb instead. Because in Array Jan is at 0. Hence `args[0]-1`

```
String[] months = ("jan","Feb", "March", "April", .... , "Dec"); //Create array of months
```

Integer.parseInt(args[0]-1) parses the input into integer (Since the input from console in java is always in string format , so it converts string numbers into int)

```
System.out.println(months[Integer.parseInt(args[0]-1)]);//prints out the month[] array value according to the index input, to the console.
```

Answer (score 2):

You pass the month number (a number between 1 and 12) and print out the corresponding name. Since array indices start at zero you subtract 1 so that running the program with an argument of 1 will print "jan" and not "Feb".

And yes you do have a typo in the capitalization. And yes I suspect this needs moving to SO.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass args[0] - 1, assuming that you want "January" as result for 1.
even though logic states that January is the 1st element of the array, arrays in Java are 0-based, meaning the indexes go from 0 to numberOfElements-1